# How to obtain 2 SELECT results from a single store procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a store procedure sp1, which has 2 SELECT results.

My question is: in another sp2, how can I obtain and reuse these 2 results from sp1?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: you get both result set from sp but issue with your driver logic to get data..